# C++ Regarding unsigned long long

Tags: c++

Why does (unsigned long long) -1 = 18446744073709551615. Is there anyway to ensure -1 stays -1 ? As I am currently picking up C++, I'm new.

```
unsigned long long a = -1;
cout << a << endl;
cout << (a >= 0) << endl;  //This returns 1 which is what I don't understand. 1 is 
                           //true for C++ right?
```

Comment: You are explicitly asking for `unsigned` - why do you think this would allow a negative (i.e. signed) number? I think you may misunderstand what `unsigned` means.

Comment: Do you know what `unsigned` means?

Comment: Why would you expect **unsigned** type to hold a **signed** value?

Comment: if `(a >= 0)` is ever `false` for an `unsigned` then something very fishy is going on

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: That remind me of real snippet of code that checked for compiler's insanity. Believe it or not, either some programmers or compilers of past were that bad. Also consider  case of comparing signed and unsigned, if one value is negative. You may get unexpected results. What John Law said about wrapping up is technically platform dependant, because some architectures use direct code instead of inverted.

Answer (score 0):

The very definition of `unsigned` means that the type doesn't allow negative integers (which are 'signed'). If you set an unsigned long long variable to `-n`, C++ *should* wrap all the way around to `2^64 - n`.

`unsigned long long`'s *should* never be negative. Thus, `(a >= 0)` will always evaluate to `true`.

If you want to store a large value but still maintain a `-1`, consider using `long long` (without the `unsigned`).

Comment: Some compilers?!?

Comment: "_Some compilers wrap all the way around_" It is defined by the standard to be the value modulo 2^n (where n is the bits necessary to represent the type), if the value is too large to fit into the unsigned type. So, no, not _some_ compilers. _All_ compilers are required to behave in such a way.

Comment: Thanks @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @NathanOliver Maybe the "some compilers" part is referring to the `64` part. In theory be`unsigned long long` is allowed to be larger than 64 bit.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am an amateur in high school. I wouldn't understand a thing about "`64` parts" (unfortunately). Sorry for the mislead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Could be.  That's why I asked for clarification.  Could easily used `2^(bit width) - n`

Comment: @JohnLaw I mean that `unsigned long long` *usually* wraps around `2^64` because `unsigned long long` is *usually* 64 bit wide. But the standard allows for platforms that have even larger `unsigned long long` types, though I don't know if such a platform has been actually implemented.

Comment: @NathaOliver also on some platforms negative format use direct code, thus the formula would be wrong. Direct code is where sign bit designates sign, and rest designate value, no inversion and -1.